# What does it mean when Community is shown as the last activity on a question?

Tags: support, community-user

I noticed [Community](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/-1/community) showing up as the last activity on a few questions, but didn't appear there were any edits or Community wiki or any recent activity. Is there just cleanup going on with it, or something else?

For example, this shows activity on the home page:
[What corporations can I run missions for and avoid losing standings with the major factions?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/23897/what-corporations-can-i-run-missions-for-and-avoid-losing-standings-with-the-majo), but has no apparent recent activity.

Comment: Yup, this question got simply bumped by Community.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The community user bumps older questions that have no upvoted answers, that is the most likeliest explanation. The other possibility if you have sub-10k reputation is that there is a post deleted by spam flags that you cannot see, those flags cause deletion by the community user.

Comment: A third possibility is an accepted suggested edit by an anonymous user - community is the owner of any revision in this case.