# When are questions bounced back to the top?

Tags: support, questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What makes a question active?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4560/what-makes-a-question-active)

I realized that some questions are bounced to the top, as if they were posted just now. I thought this would occur whenever a new answer is posted, but somehow this is not true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Questions are bumped when they are **Answered**, when the question or any of it's answers are **Edited**, or when a **Bounty** is offered.

Additionally, the **Community** user bot will [periodically bump questions with no upvoted answers.](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2987/what-does-it-mean-when-community-is-shown-as-the-last-activity-on-a-question)

Comment: This also happens even if the new answer is later deleted or the bounty revoked, making it seem like—to a user with less than 10k or  who doesn't check the revisions list—the post was bumped for none of these reasons.

Answer (score 1):

This happens either when a new answer is posted, the question or an answer is edited, and sometimes, an old unanswered question will be bumped automatically  by community.

Answer (score 1):

Also take note that question won't be 'bounced back' if you're on the [newest questions](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=newest) tab.

Comment: This was my problem. Thanks!